# Save File in Dropbox Uri

Tags: java, android, file, uri, android-contentresolver

I need to know how I can save a file that I have in Dropbox (after having modified it).

I have the dropbox URI: "**content: //com.dropbox.android.FileCache/filecache/cf9e7a01-dcee-47b3-9e4e-8c78e470d313**"

The code that I have been testing is the following:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

OutputStream out= null;
try {
        out = cr.openOutputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    wb.write(out); //look at the rest of the code fragments to understand

  //RESULT --> dropboxfile not UPDATED
```

I do not know how I can do to pass the `FileOutputStream` that I have as a result of my excel, to the creation of the Dropbox file (in `OutputStream`?)

The file that I am going to save is an excel sheet, that before saving it, I fill it with the following code:

```
 Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
 //... 
 //code to fill wb
 //...
 File fileDest = new File(path, "aux.xls");
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(fileDest);
        wb.write(os);
```

I think it can be done using "ContentResolver", which is what I used to read the file from dropbox, but I do not know how to use it to create a file using a URI

I read the file with this code:

```
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream istr =null;

        try {
            istr = cr.openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Workbook wb = null;
                try {

                    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(istr);
                    istr.close();
```

Also, this is the code of the **intent** that give me the Dropbox URI:

```
      Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      fileintent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
      try {
            startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //lbl.setText("No activity can handle picking a file. 
                 Showing alternatives.");
      }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have already added the intent code to the code, sorry.

Comment: `do not know how to use it to create a file using a URI`. Create a file? The user selected a file. So a file is already there. What do you want: change that file or create a new one? Unclear.

Comment: `AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
                InputStream inStream;` ?? Why do you have that nonsense there? Please remove it.

Comment: The user selects an excel file from Dropbox, it is processed by the application, and now I want to save it (in its Dropbox path). For this I have the URI of the original file. I do not know if I explain ...

Comment: You read the contents of that file using a input stream you got from getContentResolver().openInputStream(). Now how would one obtain/open an output stream to write the changed content to?

Comment: That's my question ... I do not know how to do it. I know that there is a function of the content resolver, `openOutputStream ()`but I do not know if I can use it here

Comment: It is the first thing you should have tried of course. What else! If you dont know you should try.

Comment: Of course it's the first thing I've tried (I've been with it for days), so I mention in the question that I think is resolved with `ContentResolver`; but I can not make it work ...

Comment: You should have posted the complete code you tried instead of that which you posted now. As what you posted now makes no sense at all.

Comment: I did not put the code that I tried because I think it's all wrong. And maybe someone could give me a totally different solution. Now, I have edited with the whole code.

Comment: `os = new FileOutputStream(out.toString()); // ---> ERROR`. Remove that line. Its nonsense. After that tell what the resulting code does.

Comment: The result is that my file dropbox is not modified. Does nothing.

Comment: So you can open the output stream? You have no catch doing so? If you had a FileNotFoundException then how would the user of your app know that there was one? You should put a Toast() in that catch block and display e.getMessage(). And then return as it does not make sense continuing with your code if you cannot open the stream. Please adapt your code and try out. Then adapt the code here and report.